# std::shared_ptr & boost::shared_ptr difference

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

I've the following code:

```
// interface.h
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H    

#include <memory>    
class IInterface {
public:
    virtual ~IInterface() = 0;
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};
inline IInterface::~IInterface() {}

typedef std::shared_ptr< IInterface > IIntPtr;    
IIntPtr makeInterface();    
#endif // INTERFACE_H


// impl.cpp
#include "interface.h"

class Interface : public IInterface { public:
    Interface() {}
    ~Interface() {}
    void doSomething() {} };

IIntPtr makeInterface() { return IIntPtr( new Interface() ); }

// main.cpp
#include "interface.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto p = makeInterface();
    p->doSomething();
}
```

Now: if i use `typedef std::shared_ptr< IInterface > IIntPtr;` all is fine, but if I use `typedef boost::shared_ptr< IInterface > IIntPtr;` I've some compiler error:

- Compiler Error C2027: A type cannot be used until it is defined. To resolve the error, be sure the type is fully defined before referencing it.
- Compiler Error C2079: 'identifier' uses undefined class/struct/union 'name'
- Compiler Error C2440: The compiler cannot cast from 'type1' to 'type2'.

I'm using msvc10, but the code must compile with msvc9.0 so I have to use Boos.SmartPtr

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you also include the appropriate header when you switch to use boost?

Comment: Are you including the Boost header, `"boost/shared_ptr.hpp"`? The standard header `<memory>` only defines the standard `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: yes: #include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp> when i use boost and <memory> when I use c++11

Comment: @elvis:  It needs to be "boost/shared_ptr.hpp" not **scoped_ptr**

Comment: ok... i also include #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>. I've no more issue. Ooops... I'm so stupid... I've lost lots of time for stupid thing

Answer (score 0):

OP answered his own question in the comments: he forgot to `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>` when trying the Boost version.